# Ubuntu 14 JVM - Could not reserve enough space for the card marking array

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

After upgrade to Ubuntu 14, I have issue with all JVMs crashing.

I reinstall Java (oracle and openjdk versions).
I spend sometime tuning the JVM heap parameters, and now finally, I can run Java apps.

Now the issue is that every time I start SQLDeveloper, my Eclipse JVM gives me: "Could not reserve enough space for the card marking array".

If I understand correctly, It's something to do with the JVM memory chunks allocation.

Is there rule I have to follow to prevent this from happening?

Machine Info:

> Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; 64-bit; CPU Intel Core2 Duo; 8GB memory
>
> Eclipse:
>    java-7-oracle; 
>    -d64; 
>    -XX:MaxPermSize=256M;
>    -Xms512m -Xmx512m;
>
> Eclipse Run/Debug: 
>    java-6-openjdk-amd64; 
>    -Xms1024m; 
>    -Xmx1024m;
>    -XX:+UseSerialGC;
>
> SQLDeveloper:
>   java-7-oracle; 
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256M;

Comment: Please update your question with your machine specs and the changes you made to JVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JVM is trying to allocate a contiguous block of memory. 
Since I have enough memory on the system, it must be fragmented.

To resolve the issue, I set the initial heap size very low (default 128 didn't work), and allowed JVM to deal with it.

I changed the JVM execution parameters from:

```
java-6-openjdk-amd64; -Xms1024m; -Xmx1024m;
```

To:

```
java-6-openjdk-amd64; -Xms64m; -Xmx1024m;
```

**Update:**

I also lowered the overcommit_ratio from 100 (default) to 50.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio
```

I know it's recommended to keep it 100, but since I've made the change, I dont get the jvm errors, when I run Chromium/Eclipse/SQLDeveloper in parallel.